# Why is the charge Q multiplied by -1, when calculating the z component of the magnetic Force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

[image]

This question is from a practice exam, and this is the solution that the teacher gave. I don't understand why the charge is multiplied by a -1, when calculating the z-component of the magnetic force. Can you explain to me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of the cross product:
$$F_z = q(v_xB_y - v_yB_x)$$
With $v_x = 0,$
$$F_z = q(0 - v_yB_x) = -qv_yB_x$$

Answer (score 0):

The full expression for $F_z$ is $q(-v_y B_x+v_xB_y)$, but $v_x=0$ in your setup, so only the term with the negative sign remains.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way the magnetic force is calculated:
[image]

If you don''t know how to calculate the determinant you can read it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant).